# Unable to access file:log4j.properties, but have told Maven to use only log4j2

Tags: java, maven, logging, intellij-idea, log4j2

I'm getting this message:

> ERROR StatusLogger Unable to access file:log4j.properties
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or
>   directory)... (+ stacktrace)

...despite telling Maven to get 2.1 AND I have log4j2.xml AND I do not have a log4j.properties. My log4j2.xml is working very well doing just what I want it to.

I get this in the console whenever I run JUnit (4.x) tests.

I am using IntelliJ to Run/Debug. I'm using JDK 1.8.0_25.

It is true that this is the first time I've used log4j 2.x, but I do not understand why this stacktrace is showing up as if I had log4j 1.x JARs or were asking for log4j 1.x.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cda-feeder ---
[INFO] com.imatsolutions:cda-feeder:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- sax:sax:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

My *log4j2.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="LEVEL">trace</Property>
    <Property name="log-path">/var/log/search/</Property>
    <Property name="logfile-size">1 GB</Property>
    <Property name="cda-filter">cda-filter</Property>
    <Property name="console-pattern">%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</Property>
    <Property name="file-pattern">   %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}: %m%n    </Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p | %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="rollingfile"
                 fileName="${log-path}/${cda-filter}.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/${cda-filter}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
                 append="true">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${file-pattern}" />
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${logfile-size}" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4" />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="root" level="${LEVEL}" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="rollingfile" level="${LEVEL}" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="${LEVEL}" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="console" />
      <AppenderRef ref="rollingfile" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: When are you having this error? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: You may have log4j ("1") on your classpath anyway - it may come with one of your dependencies. Try running `mvn dependency:tree` and see if it's there.

Comment: It looks like you are providing a Log4j 1 properties file to Log4j 2. That is not supported.